# Why is NASA waiting until Artemis V to bring a rover?

Tags: nasa, rovers, artemis-program, lunar-rover

Crewed moon rovers will be a 55 year old technology by the time Artemis III and IV launch, and historically they greatly increased the amount of time lunar astronauts could spend doing science instead of walking between points of interest, so why is NASA waiting until V to bring even an unpressurized rover? Whats more, V seems to be a specifically bad choice, as the rover is planned to be launched alongside Orion in the SLS stack, because they are using the Blue Origin lander for that mission; if they sent the rover on III or IV, they could easily fit the rover, or even a pressurized rover, in the larger Starship lander.

Comment: Can you add a source for this being the current mission order? This is probably a fast moving and very fluid area where the answer will probably change many times between now and whenever (If?) Artemis V flies. Also plenty of second hand/best guess information floating around that does not help.

Comment: Uninformed speculation is that Starship is in no position to lock in any design features relevant to a rover (hatch appears to have failed during March 2024 test). SLS and Blue Origin are better positioned in 2024 to pin down specific and critically important details like mating hardware, sizes, weight and how the thing gets onto the lunar surface after landing.

Comment: @GremlinWranger Blue Origin has yet to send ANYTHING to orbit, so I can't see how it is better positioned than SpaceX for Artemis.

Comment: neither of them are in position for anybody to be designing a rover, but I suspect there is a team somewhere needing to be paid this budget for design work, and fitting a design to Blue Origin was easier for THEM so that is what they did. This question has much more to do with US politics than sensible engineering.

Comment: From [Artemis 3 wiki page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Artemis_3): "Before the Artemis 3 landing, some additional equipment will be pre-positioned on the surface, including an unpressurized rover for astronauts to use during their lunar excursions. This rover will have the capability to be controlled remotely. Several permanently shadowed regions could be reached by short forays of 5 to 15 km (3.1 to 9.3 mi), well within the range of the rover."

Comment: @ShawnLim Huh. The wiki page for the Lunar Terrain Vehicle says it won't be used until Artemis V, so what rover would we used on III and IV? The citation on the Artemis III page is a 2019 article that doesn't have any additional information.